# AngularJs day of the week - number in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

How do i get the day of the week in angular.

eg. sunday = 00, monday = 01 etc.

I know about the date filter:
(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) but the week day number apparently doesn't exist.

The problem that the date comes from a post date in ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
   <span class="daycontainer day{{post.date | date: (daynumberformat) }}">
</div>
```

I know there is a javascript function getDay() but i do not get it to work

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts"> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var d = new Date({{post.date}});
        var dn = d.getDay();
        document.getElementById("{{post.id}}").className += " day" + dn;
    </script>
    <span id="{{post.id}}" class="daycontainer">{{post.date | date : "EEEE, MMMM d, y"}}</span>
</div>
```

the result is:

```
<span id="1-posttitle" class="daycontainer dayNaN ng-binding dayNaN dayNaN dayNaN dayNaN dayNaN dayNaN dayNaN dayNaN dayNaN dayNaN dayNaN">friday, february 26, 2016</span>
```

Comment: Angular is javscript so use javascript Date methods

Comment: `EEEE` gives you the string/name of the day of the week, but you need the number day of the week(0-6), right?

Comment: The problem is that the date comes from a ng-repeat post date

Comment: If *post.date* is not parsable by the Date constructor, then `new Date({{post.date}})` will return a Date object whose *timevalue* is NaN and calling any Date method like *getDay* will return NaN too. What is the actual value of *post.date*? Note that parsing strings with the Date constructor is well known to be unreliable and strongly advised against.

Answer (score 1):

As @charlietfl said, you can use javascript Date object :

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

For example, using getDay() function :

```
var day = (new Date()).getDay();
```

All the link in the world, to please raging people :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/getDay
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/date_getday.htm
- http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf (see pp.339-357 for Date)

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, ECMA-262 or MDN are far better resources. And the OP is already using *getDay*, the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: As you can see, the initial post has been edited 15 hours ago at the moment I'm writing this. My answer was postd 16 hours ago. Do you really think I would propose a solution already present in the question ?!